# stylelint with gulp-stylelint - error: TypeError: Cannot read property 'warnings' of undefined in node_modules/gulp-stylelint/dist/index.js:177

Tags: javascript, gulp, stylelint

I have searched and am unable to find an answer to my issue.  It is saying 'warnings'is undefined in the gulp-stylelint/index.js file - to clarify, I have not touched this file as it is a "3rd-party" file.  I get the same error whether I run it from the command line (gulp lint:css) or during the build process.

Here is the error message:

```
[vagrant@MCOM-DEV mcom-web]$ gulp lint:css
Building Project Version: undefined
Building for Environment: production
[15:24:48] Using gulpfile ~/Projects/menards.com/mcom-web/gulpfile.js
[15:24:48] Starting 'lint:css'...
/home/vagrant/Projects/menards.com/mcom-web/node_modules/gulp-stylelint/dist/index.js:177
          var errors = res.results[0].warnings.filter(isErrorSeverity);
                                      ^

TypeError: Cannot read property 'warnings' of undefined
    at /home/vagrant/Projects/menards.com/mcom-web/node_modules/gulp-stylelint/dist/index.js:177:39
    at Array.reduce (<anonymous>)
    at /home/vagrant/Projects/menards.com/mcom-web/node_modules/gulp-stylelint/dist/index.js:176:38
    at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:132:7)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:181:9)
[vagrant@MCOM-DEV mcom-web]$
```

Here is my dependencies in the package.json file:

```
      "dependencies": {
    "@babel/polyfill": "^7.0.0",
    "axios": "^0.18.0",
    "lodash": "^4.17.10",
    "popper.js": "^1.14.4",
    "uuid-js": "^0.7.5",
    "vue": "^2.5.2",
    "vuex": "^3.0.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.0.0",
    "@babel/plugin-syntax-jsx": "^7.0.0",
    "@babel/plugin-transform-modules-commonjs": "^7.0.0",
    "@babel/plugin-transform-runtime": "^7.0.0",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.0.0",
    "@babel/runtime": "^7.0.0",
    "autoprefixer": "^9.1.5",
    "babel-eslint": "^9.0.0",
    "babel-helper-vue-jsx-merge-props": "^2.0.3",
    "babel-loader": "^8.0.2",
    "babel-plugin-dynamic-import-node": "^2.1.0",
    "babel-plugin-transform-vue-jsx": "^4.0.1",
    "chalk": "^2.0.1",
    "copy-webpack-plugin": "^4.0.1",
    "cssnano": "^4.1.0",
    "eslint": "^5.6.1",
    "eslint-friendly-formatter": "^4.0.1",
    "eslint-loader": "^2.1.0",
    "eslint-plugin-vue": "^4.0.0",
    "friendly-errors-webpack-plugin": "^1.6.1",
    "gulp": "^3.9.1",
    "gulp-dart-sass": "^0.9.1",
    "gulp-eslint": "^5.0.0",
    "gulp-gzip": "^1.4.2",
    "gulp-postcss": "^8.0.0",
    "gulp-stylelint": "^7.0.0",
    "gulp-tar": "^2.1.0",
    "stylelint": "^9.6.0",
    "stylelint-config-recommended-scss": "^3.2.0",
    "stylelint-config-standard": "^18.2.0",
    "stylelint-order": "^1.0.0",
    "stylelint-scss": "^3.3.1",
    "uglifyjs-webpack-plugin": "^1.1.1",
    "vue-loader": "^15.4.1",
    "vue-template-compiler": "^2.5.2",
    "webpack": "^4.17.2",
    "yargs": "^12.0.2"
  },
```

Here is my .stylelintrc file:

```
    {
  "extends": [
    "stylelint-config-standard",
    "stylelint-config-recommended-scss"
  ],
  "plugins": [
    "stylelint-order"
  ],
  "rules": {
    "at-rule-empty-line-before": null,
    "at-rule-name-space-after": "always",
    "at-rule-no-vendor-prefix": true,
    "at-rule-semicolon-space-before": "never",
    "block-closing-brace-empty-line-before": null,
    "block-closing-brace-newline-after": null,
    "block-opening-brace-space-before": null,
    "color-named": "never",
    "declaration-block-semicolon-newline-after": "always-multi-line",
    "declaration-block-semicolon-newline-before": "never-multi-line",
    "declaration-block-semicolon-space-after": "always-single-line",
    "declaration-empty-line-before": null,
    "declaration-no-important": true,
    "font-family-name-quotes": "always-where-recommended",
    "font-weight-notation": [
      "numeric",
      {
        "ignore": [
          "relative"
        ]
      }
    ],
    "function-url-no-scheme-relative": true,
    "function-url-quotes": "always",
    "length-zero-no-unit": true,
    "max-empty-lines": 2,
    "max-line-length": null,
    "media-feature-name-no-vendor-prefix": true,
    "media-feature-parentheses-space-inside": "never",
    "media-feature-range-operator-space-after": "always",
    "media-feature-range-operator-space-before": "never",
    "no-descending-specificity": null,
    "no-duplicate-selectors": true,
    "number-leading-zero": "never",
    "media-feature-name-no-unknown": [
      true,
      {
        "ignoreMediaFeatureNames": [
          "prefers-reduced-motion"
        ]
      }
    ],
    "order/properties-order": [
      "position",
      "top",
      "right",
      "bottom",
      "left",
      "z-index",
      "box-sizing",
      "display",
      "flex",
      "flex-align",
      "flex-basis",
      "flex-direction",
      "flex-wrap",
      "flex-flow",
      "flex-shrink",
      "flex-grow",
      "flex-order",
      "flex-pack",
      "align-content",
      "align-items",
      "align-self",
      "justify-content",
      "order",
      "float",
      "width",
      "min-width",
      "max-width",
      "height",
      "min-height",
      "max-height",
      "padding",
      "padding-top",
      "padding-right",
      "padding-bottom",
      "padding-left",
      "margin",
      "margin-top",
      "margin-right",
      "margin-bottom",
      "margin-left",
      "overflow",
      "overflow-x",
      "overflow-y",
      "-webkit-overflow-scrolling",
      "-ms-overflow-x",
      "-ms-overflow-y",
      "-ms-overflow-style",
      "columns",
      "column-count",
      "column-fill",
      "column-gap",
      "column-rule",
      "column-rule-width",
      "column-rule-style",
      "column-rule-color",
      "column-span",
      "column-width",
      "orphans",
      "widows",
      "clip",
      "clear",
      "font",
      "font-family",
      "font-size",
      "font-style",
      "font-weight",
      "font-variant",
      "font-size-adjust",
      "font-stretch",
      "font-effect",
      "font-emphasize",
      "font-emphasize-position",
      "font-emphasize-style",
      "font-smooth",
      "src",
      "hyphens",
      "line-height",
      "color",
      "text-align",
      "text-align-last",
      "text-emphasis",
      "text-emphasis-color",
      "text-emphasis-style",
      "text-emphasis-position",
      "text-decoration",
      "text-indent",
      "text-justify",
      "text-outline",
      "-ms-text-overflow",
      "text-overflow",
      "text-overflow-ellipsis",
      "text-overflow-mode",
      "text-shadow",
      "text-transform",
      "text-wrap",
      "-webkit-text-size-adjust",
      "-ms-text-size-adjust",
      "letter-spacing",
      "-ms-word-break",
      "word-break",
      "word-spacing",
      "-ms-word-wrap",
      "word-wrap",
      "overflow-wrap",
      "tab-size",
      "white-space",
      "vertical-align",
      "direction",
      "unicode-bidi",
      "list-style",
      "list-style-position",
      "list-style-type",
      "list-style-image",
      "pointer-events",
      "-ms-touch-action",
      "touch-action",
      "cursor",
      "visibility",
      "zoom",
      "table-layout",
      "empty-cells",
      "caption-side",
      "border-spacing",
      "border-collapse",
      "content",
      "quotes",
      "counter-reset",
      "counter-increment",
      "resize",
      "user-select",
      "nav-index",
      "nav-up",
      "nav-right",
      "nav-down",
      "nav-left",
      "background",
      "background-color",
      "background-image",
      "filter",
      "background-repeat",
      "background-attachment",
      "background-position",
      "background-position-x",
      "background-position-y",
      "background-clip",
      "background-origin",
      "background-size",
      "border",
      "border-color",
      "border-style",
      "border-width",
      "border-top",
      "border-top-color",
      "border-top-style",
      "border-top-width",
      "border-right",
      "border-right-color",
      "border-right-style",
      "border-right-width",
      "border-bottom",
      "border-bottom-color",
      "border-bottom-style",
      "border-bottom-width",
      "border-left",
      "border-left-color",
      "border-left-style",
      "border-left-width",
      "border-radius",
      "border-top-left-radius",
      "border-top-right-radius",
      "border-bottom-right-radius",
      "border-bottom-left-radius",
      "border-image",
      "border-image-source",
      "border-image-slice",
      "border-image-width",
      "border-image-outset",
      "border-image-repeat",
      "outline",
      "outline-width",
      "outline-style",
      "outline-color",
      "outline-offset",
      "box-shadow",
      "opacity",
      "-ms-interpolation-mode",
      "page-break-after",
      "page-break-before",
      "page-break-inside",
      "transition",
      "transition-delay",
      "transition-timing-function",
      "transition-duration",
      "transition-property",
      "transform",
      "transform-origin",
      "perspective",
      "appearance",
      "animation",
      "animation-name",
      "animation-duration",
      "animation-play-state",
      "animation-timing-function",
      "animation-delay",
      "animation-iteration-count",
      "animation-direction",
      "animation-fill-mode",
      "fill",
      "stroke"
    ],
    "property-no-vendor-prefix": true,
    "rule-empty-line-before": null,
    "scss/dollar-variable-default": [
      true,
      {
        "ignore": "local"
      }
    ],
    "selector-attribute-quotes": "always",
    "selector-list-comma-newline-after": "always",
    "selector-list-comma-newline-before": "never-multi-line",
    "selector-list-comma-space-after": "always-single-line",
    "selector-list-comma-space-before": "never-single-line",
    "selector-max-attribute": 2,
    "selector-max-class": 4,
    "selector-max-combinators": 4,
    "selector-max-compound-selectors": 4,
    "selector-max-empty-lines": 1,
    "selector-max-id": 0,
    "selector-max-specificity": null,
    "selector-max-type": 2,
    "selector-max-universal": 1,
    "selector-no-qualifying-type": true,
    "selector-no-vendor-prefix": true,
    "string-quotes": "double",
    "value-keyword-case": "lower",
    "value-list-comma-newline-after": "never-multi-line",
    "value-list-comma-newline-before": "never-multi-line",
    "value-list-comma-space-after": "always",
    "value-no-vendor-prefix": true
  }
}
```

and here is the relevant part of my gulp file:

```
    'use strict';

const autoprefixer = require('autoprefixer');
const chalk = require('chalk');
const cssnano = require('cssnano');
const eslint = require('gulp-eslint');
const gulp = require('gulp');
const gzip = require('gulp-gzip');
const postcss = require('gulp-postcss');
const sass = require('gulp-dart-sass');
const spawn = require('child_process').spawn;
const stylelint = require('gulp-stylelint');
const tar = require('gulp-tar');
const webpack = require('webpack');

const pkg = require('./package');
const projectVersion = require('yargs').argv.projectVersion;

process.env.NODE_ENV = /.*SNAPSHOT.*/i.test(projectVersion)
  ? 'development'
  : 'production';

console.log(`Building Project Version: ${JSON.stringify(projectVersion)}`);
console.log(`Building for Environment: ${process.env.NODE_ENV}`);

// Lint CSS files
gulp.task('lint:css', () => {
  return gulp.src(`${__dirname}/src/scss/**/*.scss`)
    .pipe(stylelint({
      reporters: [
        {formatter: 'string', console: true}
      ]
    }));
});
```

I'm sure it is probably something I'm doing wrong, but I don't know what?

Comment: It's difficult to pinpoint where the problem might be as there are layers of tooling (and configuration) at work here. You should try to systematically rule out each tool. I suggest you start by running stylelint via the command line with your current stylelint configuration. If that works then the problem is likely with your gulp configuration or the gulp-stylelint tool itself. If it doesn't then revisit your stylelint configuration - start small, perhaps with just a single rule you know will fail, and build up by extending the other shared configs and adding plugins.

Comment: Thanks for commenting :)  I have tried running just the gulp command ( gulp lint:css ) from the terminal/command line and I receive the same error.  Were you meaning running it a different way on the command line?  I believe that is what I put in the first example of the error message above?

Comment: Yes, I mean run stylelint outside of gulp. stylelint is the tool that actually lints your styles. gulp is a task runner, which you're using to run stylelint. You can run stylelint without gulp. The easiest way to this on the command line: `./node_modules/.bin/stylelint "src/scss/**/*.scss"`. If this works, then you know the problem is with your gulp configuration and not with stylelint itself or your stylelint configuration. This can be your first step in pinpointing where the problem might be by eliminating each suspect by one-by-one.

Comment: Thank you - I will give that a try and let you know.

Comment: That command worked without the error - so something with the gulp then I'm guessing?

Comment: Yes, that seems likely. I'm not familiar with gulp I'm afraid. I only know stylelint. Good luck continuing to narrow down the problem within your gulp configuration and plugins, though.

Comment: @BeckyBoyce - do you by change have files in .stylelintignore that are being passed in by the gulp src glob?

I get the same error as you and only by manually removing the ignore files from the glob could I get the process Lint plugin to finish.

Comment: yes I do...  I decided to go a different way and not use the gulp-stylelint.  I created a gulp task that uses webpack and stylelint directly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I decided to go without using the gulp-stylelint package.  I just used webpack and stylelint directly like so:

```
'use strict';

const autoprefixer = require('autoprefixer');
const chalk = require('chalk');
const eslint = require('gulp-eslint');
const gulp = require('gulp');
const postcss = require('gulp-postcss');
const spawn = require('child_process').spawn;
const webpack = require('webpack');
const stylelint = require('stylelint');

var exec = require('child_process').exec;

// Lint CSS files
gulp.task('lint:css', (done) => {
    stylelint.lint({
      files: `${__dirname}/src/scss/**/*.scss`,
      formatter: 'string', console: true
    })
      .then(function(data) {
        if(data.output) {
          process.stdout.write(data.output.toString({ colors: true }) + '\n\n');
          console.log(chalk.red('  lint:css failed with violations.\n'));
          done();
          process.exit(1);
        }
        done();
      })
      .catch(function(err) {
        console.error(err.stack);
          done(err);
      });
});
```

I used webpack to call exec and then used the sample code to start with on the stylelint packages node.js example in it.  I hope that makes sense...